# Please recommend an one stop popular website for inspirational web design interfaces/ design snippet

Tags: web-development, website-design

Please recommend an one stop popular website for inspirational web design interfaces/ design snippet.

Comment: google... best for all ;-)

Comment: This has been converted to community wiki because there is no correct answer this question and it is open ended.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite:
http://dribbble.com/

Comment: thanks :), are u a web designer? please share some more favorites websites.

Comment: You are welcome! I am mostly involved with web programming. But for some smaller projects when I have to fill in the designer role as well I use [dribbble](http://dribbble.com/) because I can search easily by tags/color/etc.

Comment: @Jeet - Welcome to our community! This site is for answering specific questions related to being a webmaster.  Please read the FAQ, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq to get a good understanding of the best way to use the site.  If you want to discuss what someones favorites sites are, the best place to do it is here, http://chat.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

[CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/)

Answer (score 0):

- css-tricks.com
- smashing magazine
- codrops